# How can I display data 14 times more efficiently, each time with a different 'where' condition using queries?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am planning to post the work schedule, this is my Model function (MYSQL query) for displaying the workers that are supposed to work on Sunday morning. Now I need to do it for each day of the week, both morning and evening. That means 14 functions. That sounds not efficient and not so convenient. Can I use a loop somehow? So it would show me the workers' names for each day? I don't know how will I manage to do it with a query and the MVC framework.

Shifts table from the database (example)

*this is the Model function* 
public function display_shifts(){

```
$this->db->select('user.fullname');
$this->db->from('shifts');
$this->db->join('user', 'shifts.user_id = user.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('sunday =', 'morning');
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

}

Comment: Change your model - use `day_name` and `day_part` as db columns. Then you may select and group by dayname and part of day.

Comment: can you provide description of both shifts and user table?

Comment: If your concern is that you'd face 14 separate database queries (which is actually a valid concern as your application grows in scale), you can just make one big general query for the whole week (thus incurring only once in the overhead of database connection, querying, etc) and parse/group/filter the output on code afterwards. It involves writing more code and it may be a bit complicated depending on what your data looks like and the exact result you need, but it would be efficient in terms of database usage.

Answer (score 1):

You table may have additional column

```
+---------+---------+
| day     | time    |
+---------+---------+
| sunday  | morning |
+---------+---------+
| tuesday | evening |
+---------+---------+
```

And the model function

```
display_shifts($day,$time){

$this->db->select('user.fullname');
$this->db->from('shifts');
$this->db->join('user', 'shifts.user_id = user.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('day =', $day);
$this->db->where('time =', $time);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
}
```

In the controller

```
$sunday_evening_workers = $this->your_model->display_shifts("sunday","evening");
```